# unable to load google static map into div in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-mobile

I am trying to load google static map image into div in JQM
 In firebug i can see the image is getting downloaded. it also shows an error saying
illegal character PNG

```
var mapRequestData = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + locationDetail + "&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7&markers=color:green%7&sensor=false";

$.getJSON(mapRequestData + "&callback=?", function (data) {

    $('#map').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');
    $("#map").page();
});
```

Any help of suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#map').html('<img src="'+mapRequestData+'"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nauphal
I had solved the same by applying following code

var mapRequestData = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + locationDetail + "&zoom=9&size=400x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7&markers=color:green%7&sensor=false";

$(".mapImage").attr('src', mapRequestData);